# How to prevent amp-twitter component from breaking AMP validation

Tags: twitter, amp-html

I use `<amp-twitter>` component to embed twitter data into my page:

```
<amp-twitter
  width="375"
  height="472"
  layout="responsive"
  data-tweetid="885634330868850689"
>
</amp-twitter>
```

but the resulted page doesn't pass the AMP validation. I'm getting `Custom JavaScript is not allowed.` I think it is caused by the way the embedded part is generated, namely `<script async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` tag being added to the output.

I inspected documentation page for this component with `#development=1` and it is valid. But the HTML generated there is completely different from the one I have. How this issue could be fixed?

Comment: huh? What is `<script async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"`? This works: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-twitter/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the `amp-twitter` component (which passes validation). Most likely it's a problem with your dev environment, for example, some frameworks inject custom JS to implement live reloading.

Comment: Turns out, you're right - I had additional code embedding.

Answer (score -1):

Report it as a bug to the AMP project on Github.